# Android Device Backbutton should not work

Tags: android, button

First of all i am learning android,  I am testing my Andorid app in my Samsung Galaxy S1.

My app Function is: while i am pressing RandomNumber button, it will generate Random numbers and displaying in the screen in TextArea.

But i am facing the below issues.

1. The Device back button is allow user to go back.  How i can avoid that? ( I have buttons defined in the program dynamically, only that Back button should work )
2. While shaking the phone or change the position of the phone, then the Random numbers are automatically generating.  How to avoid that?.  Please advise.

Button Creation Dynamic

```
final Button buttonToAdd = new Button(this);
            buttonToAdd.setText("RandomNumber");
```

Listener:

```
buttonToAdd.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Strvalue = (String) buttonToAdd.getText();
                if (Strvalue.equals("RandomNumber"))
                {
                    Randomnumbergeneration();
                } 
        }
    });
```

Comment: Youre not supposed to change the behaviour of the device "buttons"

Comment: Please explain what you mean by _shaking the phone_ and _moving it_. Do you mean changing the orientation?

Comment: Normally seeing the screen and after that i am going to rotate the phone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can overwrite the `Activities` `onBackPressed()` method to handle the back-button click event.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
   // put some code here or just do nothing
   // don't call super.onBackPressed() if you want to disable the back function
}
```

But if you want to publish your application you should follow the [official design guidelines](http://developer.android.com/design/index.html) and do not disable this behaviour because every android user is used to it and will find it unlikely if the back button *does not work* anymore.

Comment: Also the override annotation should be added.